# In Pl SQL how to create table by selecting other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In Pl SQL I am  creating  table by selecting other tables  but not getting result  .Give Me some idea to solve this. My Partial code.

```
             sqlstring :=q'[ create table sbs  pll 8 nologging as
     select /*+parallel(e,8)*/
     e.*  from event_t e
     where
     pid_id0  >= to_char(pin23.pin_convert.unix_to_rt_pid (pin23.pin_convert.string_to_unix_ts((trunc(sysdate)),'dd/mm/yy')))
     and poid_type in ('/event/billing/payment/voucher') ]' ;
```

Comment: Are you just assigning the command to a string variable, or do you execute it as well? If so, please show the code.

Comment: Error : PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DD" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: I want to create table With in PL SQL. The given example code Want with in  PL SQL                   Code:   create table tmp_raja  parallel 8     nologging as
                           select /*+parallel(e,8)*/
                           e.*  from event_t e
                           where
                           id_id0 >=to_char(pin23.pin_convert.unix_to_rt_id(pin23.pin_convert.string_to_unix_ts((trunc(sysdate)),'dd/mm/yy')))
                           and id_type='/event/billing/payment/voucher'

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the single quotes used in code the by using **''**

Comment: Its Getting Error
ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Comment: what is your declaration for sqlstring can you please show me that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little test case that should give you what you need:

```
create table event_t
( event_id     number
, pid_id0      number
, poid_type  varchar2(100)
);
```

I created this as I have no idea on the structure of your event_t table except what I can determine from your code.

Then in PL/SQL this works:

```
declare
   sqlstring varchar2(4000);

begin
   sqlstring := q'[create table sbs parallel  8 nologging as
                   select /*+ parallel(e, 8) */
                          e.*  
                   from   event_t e
                   where  pid_id0  >= 5
                   and    poid_type in ('/event/billing/payment/voucher')]';

    execute immediate sqlstring;
end;
```

You can then select from sbs.

I have had to change the pid_id0 predicate as I do not have your packages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Miguel-F, didn't realise my code had lost its formatting.